# Which is economical for getting Date in String format? creating date objects every time or using date instance thru calendar object

Tags: java, performance, date, calendar

I have a requirement to get current time often and covert that to string and stamp it into a file or as a file name based on business. I have learnt that creating many objects deters the performance.

Now I have two methods to do it, first by creating a Date object every time to get current time.

```
//Using Date object
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMDDHHmm");
String timeNow = sdf.format(new Date());
System.out.println(timeNow);
```

Second is to create a Calendar object and get date instance by using getTime() method.

```
//Using Calendar object to get date instance
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMDDHHmm");
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
String timeNow = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
System.out.println(timeNow);
```

which method yields better performance in terms of time and memory used? If there is any other method that'll be more efficient than these two please do share

Comment: What are your measurements for these cases and how much difference is significant for you?

Comment: What do you think, I don't see how using `Calendar` to get a date object might be more performant.. Also you might want to use `Calendar.getInstance()` and not `new GregorianCalendar()`

Comment: @Mark I'd be using this to log activities and create log file name. Unlike regular logging API I'd want date inside the message content. _Often_ will be the answer and so difference will be **significant** on the long run

Comment: Then not often as only need it once a day

Comment: @RC Well I use GregorianCalendar() to sync with the current calendar. Leap year calculation .. etc differs. Well I was thinking getTime() _won't create new object_ that's the reason

Comment: @Mark I said I'll also be using it inside the log. well there is a great part of business need that I might not be allowed to discuss... hope you don't take wrong

Comment: Your example just has a date and so does not change often so you can cache it also there are many log gin libraries so see what they do if you don't use oe

Comment: Thanks Mark will try on a open source API's code, but I think for now that extensive work is not needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a Calendar object is a relatively slow and complex action, it has to compensate for all the oddities that are inherent to dates and times such as timezones, daylight savings etc.

Your best bet is to use the Date object as your first example, see [here](http://java-performance.info/java-util-date-java-util-calendar-and-java-text-simpledateformat/) for a comparison on performance metrics of Date, Calendar and SimpleDateFormat.

Another approach could be to use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), see [here](http://java-performance.info/joda-time-performance/) for performance comparison between JodaTime and Calendar. Whilst the difference between Java Date and JodaTime is probably negligible in performance terms, JodaTime is generally agreed to be a better way of handling dates and times. For your purpose, importing JodaTime just for a timestamp may well be overkill though.

Comment: Thanks @Wabs that helps :) TFS link , it has more information than I'd require but I got the bottom line

Answer (score 1):

The first one is faster, but it's so little that you should use whatever code looks more appealing to you. The Calendar will create a new Date as well, and base it on the current time, just like your first code except in many more methods calls.

Comment: I never thought about the method calls :) thanks for the insight Xabster

Comment: I shouldn't have said that. It's not "because of more method calls". Please don't start to optimize your code by avoiding method calls. It doesn't work like that.

Comment: Oh! ok :) np I'm using the first one, also the logic is clear cut.

Answer (score 0):

If you need improved speed maybe in synchronization or database handling, the best way is to use JodaTime Library, it is 5 times faster than SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: this should be a comment